# From where the JButton was pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

All the tiles on the board are buttons, each category in separate arrays.

How can i know from which category the button is at the ActionListener without checking `.getSource()` for every element in every array ?

I could make separate ActionListeners for each category but again ill have to go through the array to get the type/color.

[image: BOARD GAME SCREENSHOT]

Maybe there is something that I don't know that would be really useful.

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Without code, we can't know how you're approaching the problem

Comment: *"Maybe there is something that I don't know that would be really useful."* Loops. Until there are 10s of thousands of buttons, it should be a doddle for a modern computer to check them each until the right button is found.

Comment: Maybe you could use method [putClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for you buttons with fields for 'color' and 'type' also which extends JButton and implements either ActionListener, MouseListener, or both...

```
public class YourButton extends JButton implements ActionListener, MouseListener { }
```

Create a constructor in that class to instantiate the YourButton object...

```
public class YourButton(string color, string type) { }
```

When you create your game board, instantiate YourButton class...

```
YourButton yb = new YourButton('color', 'type');
```

Each instance of this class has its own ActionListener and/or MouseListener, thus you can handle events from within the YourButton class and you will know the color and type because the fields will be set when you instantiate the class and create an object.

You can also treat YourButton as you would treat a JButton as it is an extension of the JButton class.